# How does Maz know this?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, Maz tells Rey about the lightsaber and its past users:

> That lightsaber was Luke's. And his father's before him. And now, it calls to you.

Then she tells Finn:

> If you live long enough, you see the same eyes in different people.

She also says of the evils in the past:

> Through the ages…I've seen evil take many forms. The Sith. The Empire. Today, it is the First Order. Their shadow is spreading across the galaxy. We must face them. Fight them. All of us."

What does she mean by "If you live long enough, you see the same eyes in different people"? And how does she know that Anakin and Luke Skywalker had the lightsaber before in the past - did she have a vison of the past showing Anakin and Luke? And how did she know about the sith and the empire like Palpatine and Darth Vader?

Comment: Well, she *is* older than Yoda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maz Kanata was born over a millennium before the conflict between the First Order and the Resistance. So she is very old and would have known about the goings on because she housed many smugglers throughout the years.

I believe she meant not the exact same physical eyes but she can tell what the person is thinking and feeling eg determined eyes.  She is also force sensitive, so not only could she know the intentions/thoughts/feelings of people by looking in their eyes (“The Eyes are the window to your soul”) she can use the force to probe further.

The empire along with emperor Palpatine would have been common knowledge among anyone living under a planet of his rule or the surrounding systems. Darth Vader being his right hand and also the face of the imperial army would be just as know if not more. Vader was not afraid to show his skills both with the dark side and his lightsaber. Maz being as old as she was and having lived through so much would easily have know Vader was a Sith. She might not have known Palpatine  was a Sith but it would not have been a wild guess on her part as he would complete the rule of two.

> Kanata spent centuries traveling the galaxy, collecting antiques and trinkets which she kept inside the storehouses and vaults of her castle. One such item was the lightsaber crafted by Jedi Knight Anakin Skywalker and later wielded by Skywalker's son, Luke, who was instrumental in toppling the Galactic Empire.

-- [Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata)

There's no canon answer to the specifics on how she got it but lightsabers being so rare it's not a wild guess for her to believe it was Luke's. Her being force sensitive and the lightsaber obviously still connected to Luke, could have also helped her to verify it's previous owner.

Comment: Where is the quote from?

Comment: @JeremyFrench starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata

Comment: Cool, thanks. If you add citation (like I did in the edit) to quotes it can help people with your answer. Some people trust wikis others trust wookies.

Comment: @JeremyFrench Thanks

Comment: but how does she know that Anakin and Luke Skywalker had the lightsaber before in the past

Comment: @AndrewCasali There's no canon answer to the specifics on how she got it but lightsabers  being so rare it's not a wild guess for her to believe it was Luke's. Her being force sensitive and the lightsaber obviously still connected to Luke, could have also helped her to verify it's previous owner.

Comment: And how did she know about the sith and the empire like Palpatine and Darth Vader?

Comment: @AndrewCasali Edited my answer.

Comment: @OceanKnight I know this is an old question at this point, but any source on Maz being force sensitive?

Comment: Answering my own question regarding Maz's force sensitivity, I found at least one source, where see says to Rey on Takodana, "I am no Jedi, but I know the Force."

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be the case that Max was someone who was near the Skywalkers at one point or friends with them. When Kylo is interrogating Rey he says "**You mean the murders, traitors and thieves you call friends?"**..... I am not 100% sure but I heard something about Maz that she stole the Saber from Kylo. Finn would be the traitor in his comment, and Han would be the murderer. Kylo Ren is a character who is honest. He only lies to Snoke, so I think it's ok to assume he was referring to Maz and Maz stole it.

*A good question for another time*